# Dynamically grow a div container on button press?

Tags: html, css, angular, materialize

I am working on the front end of a website using Angular 6 and the Materialize Framework for practice/training. I am very new to this type of development. I like the use of cards in Materialize and would like after a card reveal to have a button on the card that could grow the card to the size of the screen to make reading all the information easier. Any help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, one way is applying a different class to the card depending on a variable (which changes on button click), you do this with [class.big]="cardSize==='big'" or [class.small]="cardSize==='small'"

Please see this working example so you can undestand better.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wa4yhh

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure why I couldn't wrap my head around how simple that ended up being! Thanks again, I'm still extremely new to doing anything inside of Angular.